# change date format m/d/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy using formula

Tags: excel

```
  sr  date       date-text  mm  dd  yyyy    concat(dd,mm,yyyy)
  1   12/31/2018 12/31/2018 12  31  2018    31/12/2018
  2   3/31/2019  3/31/2019  3/  1/  2019    1//3//2019
```

as shown above i have some dates in col 'date' formatted as m/d/yyyy. i need to convert this to dd/mm/yyyy. i tried DATEVALUE funtion but it gives value error as my pc date format is dd/mm/yyyy. Unfortunately i cant change my PC date format.
So i tried to split the date using LEFT,MID and RIGHT function.

```
date-text = TEXT([@[date]],"mmm/ddd/yyyy") - to fix date format to mm/dd/yyyy
mm =LEFT([@[date-text]],2)
dd =MID([@[date-text]],4,2)
yyyy=RIGHT([@[date-text]],4)
concat(dd,mm,yyyy) = =CONCAT([@dd],"/",[@mm],"/",[@yyyy]) to get mm/dd/yyyy for mat.
```

This approach works for row 1 but for row 2 i get wrong date "1//3//2019". please let me know how to fix this

Comment: Select the dates and apply custom format dd/mm/yyyy

Comment: What is the error messages?

Comment: if you see sr.2  i am getting error date 1//3//2019. as i am not able to fix the date format to mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: @ImranMalek i want to create a refreshable file. this excel pulls data from sql. so i need formula to do this, no manual activity

Comment: Exactly How does it pull the data from sql? If the SQL statement is done properly and the originating data is in Date format, you should not have this problem to begin with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try following formula

```
=DATE(RIGHT(A1,4),LEFT(A1,SEARCH("/",A1)-1),TRIM(MID(LEFT(A1,SEARCH("/",A1,SEARCH("/",A1)+1)-1),SEARCH("/",A1)+1,2)))
```

[image]

Comment: This will result in #VALUE error if the format of the cell A1 is date which is what OP has mentioned.

Comment: Strangely enough, the formula `DATE` doesn't work on my personal computer without the `VALUE` function on every arguments. However it works fine on my companies PC without them... Eh eh... It's a wonderful Microsoft world...

Comment: @ImranMalek If `A1` cell is date formatted then you do not need this formula. Just put `=A1` in `B1` cell and format the cell as `dd/mm/yyyy`. That's enough. Or OP can directly format the `A` column with `dd/mm/yyyy` no need any further formula.

Comment: @Harun24HR That's what I suggested in my first comment but the OP wants a formula !

Comment: @Pspl `Value()` function need to convert text to value. Excel automatically do some mathematical conversion incase of number and dates if there is no text included.

Comment: @Harun24HR, you're right. I just find interesting the fact one version need it and the other doesn't. On the matter of "formatting the cell as date", you can't do that on the `3/31/2019`. Excel will NOT recognize it as date.

Comment: @Pspl That's true. If your computer date settings is `dd/mm/yyyy` and excel cell is not formatted date and enter `3/31/2019` then excel will treat it as string not as date because `31` is not any month.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the result you want with just one formula:

```
=DATE(VALUE(RIGHT(A2;4));VALUE(MID(A2;1;FIND("/";A2;1)-1));VALUE(MID(A2;FIND("/";A2;1)+1;FIND("/";A2;FIND("/";A2;1)+1)-FIND("/";A2;1)-1)))
```

I understand very well your situation. I'm from Portugal and here we have the same date format as you (`dd/mm/yyyy`). Pay attention to your pasted values as a "date". For instance, if you place `3/31/2019` Excel won't recognize it as a date and paste it as text (that's why you don't need your `date-text` column). However, if you paste `1/12/2019` Excel will write automatically `01/12/2019` when the true date is `12/01/2019` and the formula will not work.

Answer (score -1):

Simplest way for me is to use text to column function. select m/dd/yy dates and go to "Data" select text to column function located in "data tools". This enables the Text Wizard - select the delimited button. hit "next". Step 2 wizard box appears which is where you choose your delimiters. remove any ticks except for "Other" and tick this box. Click "Next". Step 3 of 3 box appears. IMPORTANT Choose your destination carefully. Ideally select a blank cell at the end of your existing data. In this way the results of the text to data function can be freely edited. If you have selected your original data correctly every cell will transpose as m - dd - yyyy. Cut and paste the year to its RH adjacent column and transpose the "m" to the blanks cells that were occupied by the "yyyy". Now you'll have 3 columns "dd", "mm", "yyyy". with a Blank column where the "m's" were. Select the blank cell to the left of the first row of transposed data. Enter the formula "=VALUE(ddcell&"/"&"mm"cell)
you should get a result of 1/01 (if that's the date your modifying). If the current year is 2022 then that will be added automatically. If not you'll have to modify your formula to include the date you want. If the result shows just a number go to your home tab and then number options. Select "Short Date" and it will all happen. With some practice this procedure is a breeze and saves writing those long messy formulas.
Good luck from Henry

Comment: Thank you for joining Stack Overflow and sharing your knowledge. However, the answer you've given is hard to read with the current layout. Could you reformat it into shorter paragraphs, perhaps even some bullet points? We don't expect every answer to be perfect, but answers with correct spelling, punctuation, and grammar are easier to read. They also tend to get upvoted more frequently.