# Convert date from d/M/yy hh:mm tt To dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm

Tags: excel, excel-formula

How can I convert a date in excel from `1/4/19 1:00 PM` to `01/04/2019 13:00`.

The date is stored as a string since the file is exported from an application as an XLS ( There is no way to modify the source )

Comment: Please add more info.  Is the date stored as a string(does changing the format not effect the look) or stored as a number(which means changing the format to `dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm` should do it.

Comment: It's stored as a string

Comment: Your question is very similar.
You can adapt this response to your format. [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53627459/change-date-format-m-d-yyyy-to-dd-mm-yyyy-using-formula)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is an image of the workflow to to convert your date from one format to another.  It wraps up by substituting all the helper cells into one formula in the end.  hard to read but does the job.

[image: Answer]

## Understanding Excel's Date and Time

### Date

Excel stores the date as an integer. It is the count of the number of days since January 0, 1900. So 1 is January 1st 1900. (I believe on Mac's the reference year is 1905 but I could be wrong). So all dates in excel are simply integers with some special formatting applied to display them in some manner we are used to seeing.  You can test this out by typing 1 in an empty cell and then change the cells format from Date toe General.  So if you need to just find the date from a mixed time date, you need to strip off just the integer portion.

### TIME

Time is stored a % of a day or if you prefer decimal of a day. 0.5 represents half a day or lunch. Again this can be tested by entering 0.5 in an empty cell and then changing the cell format from General to Time.  If you just need the time, you just need to strip of the decimal portion.

### Combined Date and Time

Based on the above, you know the date is an integer, and time is the decimal.  In order to combine the two, they simply need to be added together.  In C21,  just the date is determined.  In C22, just the time is determined.  In C23, the two elements are simply added together and a custom cell format of  YY/MM/DD HH:MM is applied.  An important difference between C23 and C28, is that C23 is a number and C28 is TEXT.

Comment: @jeeped if you are still around, I thought you might appreciated the format of this answer.

Comment: Thank you for this awesome answer, I'm going to try it but before can you tell me why the date in C32 is not in the format of 21C since you just combined everything together

Comment: C21 is just the date.  C32 is the date and time added together.  The better comparison is C23 and C32 as they are both date and time. Also updated answer with explaining how Excel stores time.

Comment: The biggest issue you are going to have is surrounding the year and how to determine if you are in the 1900s or the 2000s.  when I went through the calc the first time excel interpreted the year 19 as 1919.

Answer (score 0):

If i have a date that is displayed as a string, i typically use TextToColumns to have it recognize the date, then apply formatting as desired.  The code I run is per Column:

```
Columns("D").TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
    TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
    Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False
```

Note that I don't use any delimiters.

Then the formatting is something like:

```
Columns("D").NumberFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm""
```

---

**Edit1:**

General subroutine format looks like:

```
Sub NameofMacro()
    Columns("D").TextToColumns DataType:=xlDelimited, _
        TextQualifier:=xlDoubleQuote, ConsecutiveDelimiter:=False, Tab:=False, _
        Semicolon:=False, Comma:=False, Space:=False, Other:=False
    Columns("D").NumberFormat = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm""
End Sub
```

Comment: I never coded  on excel, is this something to use in a macro or a cell function?

Comment: @user3501194 you would run this in VBA (alt+f11 is the shortcut)... create a module and create a subroutine (will update code to reflect a full sub).